# How do you add a long list of rasters together in Python?

Tags: arcpy, raster

If you have produced a long list of rasters (lets say 50) and want to add them together, is there any shorter way to write in python rather than typing all the inputs, like so:

```
outRas = inRas1 + inRas2.........+ inRas50
```

Answer (score 9):

You can make a list of the raster names you wish to add together, then step through the list, adding each one to an output raster.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set the current workspace
# 
env.workspace = "C:/Data/DEMS"

#Check out ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")


# Get a list of ESRI GRIDs from the workspace and print
#

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "GRID")

#Step through the list of raster names
for rasname in rasterList:
    #Cast rasname as raster before adding
    listras = Raster(rasname)
    #Add each raster to an output raster.
    #The previous step of casting as a Raster will invoke
    #the Spatial Analyst Addition function.
    outras += listras

#Save output Raster
outras.save("C:/temp/outras")
```

Comment: Another possibility, once you have a list of rasters, is to use [CellStatistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007q000000.htm) with the "SUM" option.

Comment: I got what your suggestion. But, what if I have other rasters in my workspace and don't want to add them?

Comment: Because you have had the foresight to number the raster datasets systematically, simply create the list of raster names with a small loop. Alternatively, filter `rasterList` to exclude any raster you do not want to process.

Comment: I am getting error like `outras is not defined!` or python hangs!

Comment: @SIslam Without seeing your code, it is not possible to figure out what the problem is.  The comments of this question is probably not the best place to try to figure out what the problem is.  I think your best bet would be to post the problem you are having as a new question on GIS.se, along with what you are trying to do, a code sample, etc.  Then, people will be able to answer your question directly with all the pertinent information available.

Answer (score 1):

Another option may just using the python built-in `sum` function as below

**Step-1:Get list of the paths of the rasters**

```
import arcpy,os
raster_pths = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(raster_input_folder):
    for single_file in files:
        if single_file.endswith('.tif'):
            input_raster_pth = os.path.join(root,single_file)
            inpt_raster = os.path.join(root, single_file)
            raster_pths.append(inpt_raster)
```

**Step-2:Now create a list of arcpy raster using those collected rasters path-it needs memory**

```
needed_rasters_virtual = [arcpy.Raster(i) for i in needed_rasters]
```

**Step-3:Now do the sum**

```
summed_raster = sum(needed_rasters_virtual)
```

Though the above method needs a lot of memory in case of large raster but it comes handy when you need to do some complex steps at easy go like-

Say you have a value list `estimates = [ 0.292088680, -0.000046162, -0.000014440, -0.000023292, -0.000027125, -0.000000819,  0.000032517, -0.000021072,  0.000004663,  0.000047970,  0.000111651,  0.000008808, -0.000014821]` and another raster list,say `rsts` of same length. Now you want to multiply each element of the `rsts` by respective element of the `estimates` list according to their position order and after all you want to get the sum of all of these rasters.I this case this way may comes handy as below-

for the above process:

```
rsts = [arcpy.Raster(i) for i in needed_rasters]
summed_raster = sum([i*j for i,j in zip(needed_rasters_virtual,estimates)])
```