# Viewshed analysis without observer point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, viewshed, visibility, global-mapper

I want to find the most visible point within an area..
I don't have an observer point, I want to find it.

based on the highest points, I've created scenarios and compare..
However there might be an automatic way of doing it?

I have access to ArcGIS desktop (spatial analyst), QGIS or Global mapper..
the software package doesn't really matter.. I just want to know if is there something already there.

Comment: You might consider contouring the surface, then extracting the highest values and deriving their centers.

Answer (score 2):

The most visible point... From where?  From everywhere?  How big is the area?
What I suggest is creating a grid of regularly spaced points and using each one of those as observer points.

1. I usually use **[Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/)** to create regular points within a polygon.  It's free to download and open source.  Here's **[the command](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/genregularpntsinpolys.htm)** to do so.
2. Run a **[viewshed analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Viewshed/009z000000v3000000/)** from each one which will give you a raster with either a 1 (visible) or a 0 (not visible).
3. You can then add all of the rasters together into one final result.  Here's a **[post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31989/how-do-you-add-a-long-list-of-rasters-together-in-python)** on how to do this.
4. The pixels with the highest value is the most visible spot. You can use **[cell statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000)** to determine this.

Comment: Expensive exersise though. For real terrain I'd limit it to ridges, e.g. points with 0 flow accumulation at least

Comment: Assuming you've run a flow accumulation first...

Comment: Yes. Flow accumulation first. Small price to pay for making task feasible. I'd add focal statistics (max) to it and consider only points equal to it

Comment: You should add that as an answer.  I'd upvote it...

Comment: I was on the same path as you, it's only fair if your update yours